# Training, validation and test accuracy of model are fine.But all the predictions for test images results out to be belonging to class 0?

Tags: python, keras

I am working on creating a classifier to recognize the images belonging to a particular class. I have used transfer learning with ResNet50 to build my model. I have freezed all the layers and added the last layer. The total number of classes are 5. But all the test images give the prediction to be belonging to class 0. I am performing data augmentation on train and validation data before training.

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)) 
 # Top Model Block    
u = base_model.output
u = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(u)
u = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(u)
u = Dropout(0.5)(u)
predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(u)

#freezing the layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
#augmenting the train and validation data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,

                              rotation_range=transformation_ratio,
                               shear_range=transformation_ratio,
                               zoom_range=transformation_ratio,
                               cval=transformation_ratio,
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               vertical_flip=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

#prediction report
predicted1 = model.predict(x1_test)

result: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])
```

My training accuracy is 72.9% and test accuracy is 72.6%
Note: Number of epochs = 10

Please advice me as to where am I going wrong!
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: check how many no. of images belong to class 0. If more than 70% belongs to class  0, then model will do prediction like this. You should have a look on a concept 'Percision and Recall'.

Comment: I have 150 odd images belonging to class 0 out of 480 images. I have claculated the confusion matrix, according to which the precision is 1.0 and recall is 0.0.            How can I solve this?

Comment: I am not an expert in this. But one thing is, there is a trade-off between precision and recall. So, it all depends on your problem whether you want precision or recall to be high. Have a look at this article https://towardsdatascience.com/beyond-accuracy-precision-and-recall-3da06bea9f6c

Comment: Provide more code, please. What is the model structure and the activations used? What is `x1_test`?

Comment: I have stored the data in npy file and loaded the same and splitted the data into train,test and validation sets. x1 is the representation of the data. x1_train represents the training set.